# Capybara not matching radio buttons in rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a test for a Bootstrap form using rspec. I have the following code:

```
<div id="published" class="col-sm-auto">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <%= form.radio_button :published, true, checked: page.published?, class: 'custom-control-input' %>
    <%= form.label :published, 'Published', value: true, class: 'custom-control-label' %>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <%= form.radio_button :published, false, checked: !page.published?, class: 'custom-control-input' %>
    <%= form.label :published, 'Hidden', value: false, class: 'custom-control-label' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

which generates the following HTML:

```
<div id="published" class="col-sm-auto">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="true" name="page[published]" id="page_published_true" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="page_published_true">Published</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="page[published]" id="page_published_false" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="page_published_false">Hidden</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run this test, it fails with the message

```
it 'should default to unpublished' do
  expect(page).to have_checked_field('Hidden')
end
```

giving the message `expected to find visible field "page[published]" that is checked and not disabled but there were no matches. Also found "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.`

Looking at the HTML in the inspector, the field is visible and not disabled, and there is a label that matches the text. I have no idea what the two empty strings are about.

Please could somebody tell me why `have_checked_field` isn't matching? I'm really not keen on writing a more brittle test that uses `has_css` or `has_xpath` to look for an input tag with a specific ID — the whole point is that the user should see a field labelled "Hidden" and it should be checked, regardless of what's happening behind the scenes!

Comment: Are you sure the field is actually visible within the viewport? Are you capturing screenshots and/or HTML upon failure to confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll 99.9% guarantee you the radio input isn't actually visible and has been replaced by an image using CSS (and maybe some JS).  You could do

```
expect(page).to have_checked_field('Hidden', visible: false)
```

or you could do something slightly more complicated that verifies the label is actually visible like

```
expect(page).to have_css('input:checked + label', exact_text: 'Hidden')
```

Another solution if you're dealing with a lot of these radio buttons is to write a custom selector type something like

```
Capybara.add_selector(:bootstrap_radio) do 
  xpath do |locator|
    XPath.descendant(:input)[XPath.attr(:type) == 'radio'].following_sibling(:label)[XPath.string.n.is(locator)]
  end

  filter(:checked) do |node, value|
    node.sibling('input[type="radio"]', visible: :hidden).checked? == value
  end
end
```

which would then allow you to do

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:bootstrap_radio, 'Hidden', checked: true)
```

and then you could write helper methods like `have_checked_bootstrap_radio` if wanted.  Note: this code was off the cuff so the XPath/CSS expressions may not be 100% correct but the general idea is sound :)

Comment: Thanks — I haven't checked this yet, but I suspect this is what Bootstrap's doing. I'll give it a try tonight and mark this as accepted if I can get it going. Is spec_helper.rb the best place for the custom selector?

Comment: @JohnY When using custom selectors I usually put them in their own file(s) and then require them after Capybara has been included in `rails_helper`, either specifically or via a `spec/support/**/*` include.  `spec_helper` would work too as long as Capybara is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks — the first two methods work, but I get `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find non-visible css "input[type=\"radio\"]" that is a sibling of visible bootstrap_radio "Hidden"` from the custom selector. I'm not sure if this is because Bootstrap 4 sets the `z-index` to -1 rather than setting `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @JohnY then try changing to `visible: :all` instead of `visible: :hidden` in the filter. Also don't forget to accept the answer (checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.